# Javascript Array value not defined

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to get a preview box update with form data when you click on a checkbox. But it doesn't work for array values.

Here's the code:

```
    <script>
        function FillPreview(f) {

        if(f.update.checked == true) {
            f.preview_name.value = f.post_title.value;
            f.preview_description.value = f._ecp_custom_13.value;
            f.preview_date.value = f.EventStartDate.value;
            f.preview_venue_name.value = f.venue[Venue].value;
            f.preview_venue_address.value = f.venue[Address].value;
            f.preview_venue_city.value = f.venue[City].value;
            f.preview_venue_state.value = f.venue[Province].value;
            f.preview_phone.value = f.organizer[Phone].value;
            f.preview_website.value = f.organizer[Website].value;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

The following form HTML is just a summary. I'm actually using The Community Events Add-on to The Events Calendar plugin for Wordpress.

```
    <form name="eventForm">
        <input type="text" name="post_title" />
        <input type="text" name="_ecp_custom_13" />
        <input type="text" name="EventStartDate" />
        <input type="text" name="venue[Venue]" />
        <input type="text" name="venue[Address]" />
        <input type="text" name="venue[City]" />
        <input type="text" name="venue[Province]" />
        <input type="text" name="venue[Zip]" />
        <input type="text" name="organizer[Phone]" />
        <input type="text" name="organizer[Website]" />
    </form>
```

And the preview box HTML

```
    <div id="preview">
        <h2>Print Preview</h2>
        <input type="text" class="preview-date" name="preview_date" />
        <div class="preview-category" name="preview_category"></div>
        <input type="text" class="preview-name" name="preview_name" />
        <input type="text" class="preview-time" name="preview_time" />
        <input type="text" class="preview-venue-name" name="preview_venue_name" />
        <input type="text" class="preview-venue-address" name="preview_venue_address" />
        <input type="text" class="preview-venue-city" name="preview_venue_city" />
        <input type="text" class="preview-venue-state" name="preview_venue_state" />
        <input type="text" class="preview-venue-zip" name="preview_venue_zip" />
        <input type="text" class="preview-description" name="preview_description" />
        <input type="text" class="preview-phone" name="preview_phone" />
        <input type="text" class="preview-website" name="preview_website" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="update" name="update" onclick="FillPreview(this.form)" />
    </div>
```

My problem is that the array values are undefined while the other values (title, description, etc.) work just fine. Like I said before, the form code is actually from The Community Events Add-on to Wordpress's "The Events Calendar" plugin, so anybody who knows that plugin well will be more helpful.

I grabbed the javascript from [this link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/forms/article.php/3898101). I tested that on my submit event page by itself and it worked just fine. As you can see I'm an absolute script kiddie. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `f.preview_website.value = f["organizer[Website]"].value;`

Comment: That works. Thank you very much.